# reorder multi index dataframe with pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like this :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                       'date': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                       'p_id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                        '9h30': [0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16],
                        '9h35': [0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26],
                        '9h40': [0.31,0.32,0.33,0.34,0.35,0.36]})
df1.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

    9h30  9h35  9h40  date  p_id
ID                              
1   0.11  0.21  0.31     1     1
2   0.12  0.22  0.32     1     2
3   0.13  0.23  0.33     1     3
4   0.14  0.24  0.34     2     1
5   0.15  0.25  0.35     2     2
6   0.16  0.26  0.36     2     3
```

If I use `df2 = df.pivot(index='p_id', columns='date')` I get for df2 :

```
      9h30        9h35        9h40      
date     1     2     1     2     1     2
p_id                                    
1     0.11  0.14  0.21  0.24  0.31  0.34
2     0.12  0.15  0.22  0.25  0.32  0.35
3     0.13  0.16  0.23  0.26  0.33  0.36
```

But this is not exactly what I want which is df3:

```
date         1                 2
      9h30  9h35  9h40  9h30  9h35  9h40
p_id                                    
1     0.11  0.21  0.31  0.14  0.24  0.34
2     0.12  0.22  0.32  0.15  0.25  0.35
3     0.13  0.23  0.33  0.16  0.26  0.36
```

Is there a way to directly produce this output with only pivot?
If not, can you tell me how you would do it in an efficient manner.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df2 = df2.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df2)
date     1                 2            
      9h30  9h35  9h40  9h30  9h35  9h40
p_id                                    
1     0.11  0.21  0.31  0.14  0.24  0.34
2     0.12  0.22  0.32  0.15  0.25  0.35
3     0.13  0.23  0.33  0.16  0.26  0.36
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you, but can you confirm that there is no way of doing it directly from df1 to df3 with pivot?

Comment: You can use alternatives `df2 = df1.set_index(['date', 'p_id']).unstack(0)` or `df2 = df1.set_index(['p_id','date']).unstack()`, but get same problem in both. So it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

This is an explicit way. But go with [@jezrael's pandonic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788933/9209546).

```
time, date = list(df2.columns.get_level_values(0)), list(df2.columns.get_level_values(1))
df2.columns.set_levels(date, level=0, inplace=True)
df2.columns.set_levels(time, level=1, inplace=True)

#          1           2           1          2     
# date  9h30  9h30  9h30  9h30  9h30  9h30 9h30 9h30
# p_id                                              
# 1     0.11  0.14  0.21  0.24  0.31  0.34    1    4
# 2     0.12  0.15  0.22  0.25  0.32  0.35    2    5
# 3     0.13  0.16  0.23  0.26  0.33  0.36    3    6
```

Comment: I'll use @jezrael's solution, but thanks for showing another way to do it, it is always usefull to see different possibilities.